# XSLTでXMLの処理中に別のXMLを読み込んで処理する方法

Tags: xslt

XSLTで基本となるXMLを読み込んでrootから処理を行っている最中に、別のXMLファイルを読み込んで処理を行うことは可能でしょうか？可能であれば方法を教えて下さい。

例としては、
基本となるXMLのP要素を処理する際に、別のXMLファイルのP要素を参照するといった処理を想定しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML ファイルを読み込みたいだけでしたら、このあたりでできます：

- [`collection()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-collection)
- [`doc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-doc)
- [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-document)